# If a word has multiple pronunciations, how do I know which one is more commonly used?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, symbols, multiplicity

When I tried to remember English words, I met some words that has multiple pronunciations, how do I know which one is more commonly used? Or should I remember them all?

For example,
prospect, as verb its: `/prəˈspɛkt/`
as noun, its: `/ˈprɒspɛkt/`

so, as you English speakers, how do you tell the difference? I mean, if you use it as noun, you will say 
`/ˈprɒspɛkt/` and if you use it as verb you will say `/prəˈspɛkt/` ?

Or will you just say randomly?

For us English learners, should we remember all pronunciations of one word, the pronunciation of verb and pronunciation of noun or adj/adv?

Comment: You example is easy, as you say yourself. When it's a verb you pronounce it one way, as a noun the other. Why would I pronounce the verb as the noun? When it comes to words that even with the same grammatical function have several pronunciations, it largely depends on where your are... English learners should (try to) memorize pronunciation of the words they use. A noun is not a verb, if you want to use both, memorize both. The dictionary doesn't make the distinction just for fun :)

Comment: Trying to get every pronunciation of an English word right is a fool's errand.  Learn the basic pronunciation, use the word, and listen to how others use it.  You no doubt have enough of an accent that getting the IPA pronunciation "exactly right" isn't going to happen anytime soon, and most English speakers are quite tolerant of pronunciation quirks in others.

Comment: Part 1: Hot Licks is quite correct. If my English teacher hadn't pointed it out to me in Grade 12 I would've never realised I pronounced some nouns and verbs differently (such as 'content').

It's like when you look at a word and an image immediately pops up. When someone says 'cóntent' I immediately picture someone being happy/content, while when I hear 'contènt' I might picture a book's content.

Comment: Part 2: 

So to pronounce 'content' in the wrong intonation might bring up some funny imagery, but it's no different than other languages really. (Consider 'anos' in Spanish which can mean 'years' or something rather impolite depending on pronunciation).

Of course the context of the word will also help isolate the exact meaning in most cases.

Comment: @HotLicks Memorizing all pronunciations of one word is quite difficult for English learner. I wish i could easy do that. But how do I now which pronunciation is basic one?

Comment: Usually the first pronunciation a dictionary gives is the most common one. (Excepting homographs like *bow* and *bow*, and words which have different pronunciations for different parts of speech.) Of course, sometimes different regions of the U.S. use different pronunciations, but you probably shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Except in a few rare cases it doesn't really matter which pronunciation you use.  The wrong one may cause a little confusion at first, but most people will quickly compensate.

Comment: There is no way we could know which pronunciation is more commonly used as it will depend on each word's popularity. This question is too broad or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Inazuma I think you mean those the other way around. When you hear _cóntent_, you think of a book; when you hear _contènt_, you think of someone being happy and satisfied. Unless you're using the accents to mark the _unstressed_ syllables, which I'd say would be somewhat odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are asking about heteronyms, also called heterophones, rather than just dialectical differences in pronunciations. A heteronym is a word where a change in pronunciation changes the meaning, even though the spelling remains the same.

There are two kinds of heteronyms:

A) Two words with entirely unrelated meanings, usually also with either completely different or very divergent etymologies. Examples include

- *sewer*: **SO-er**, one who stitches cloth together, vs. **SOO-er**, a ditch or tunnel for carrying away waste;
- *lead*: **leed** (rhymes with bead), be in charge or in the front, vs. **lehd** (rhymes with head), the heavy base metal. This one causes further confusion because the past tense of the verb lead is led, pronounced exactly like the element lead.

This type of homonym is quite rare, and you just need to learn them through practice and content. Search for "heteronyms" or "heterophones" and you likely can find a list with most of them that you would encounter in everyday life.

B) The second kind of heteronyms are verb and noun or adjective forms of related concepts. These are more common than the first type, but luckily follow an easy pattern.

The rule is that the verb form puts the emphasis on the final syllable, while the noun or adjective generally does not. Thus:

- If you use the *appropriate* (**uh-PRO-pree-uht**) pronunciation, you
  will not accidentally *appropriate* (**uh-pro-pree-ATE**) some other
  word's meaning. So don't just randomly *alternate* (**AHL-ter-NATE**) between *alternate* (**ahl-TER-nuht**) possibilities.

and

- I'm supposed to *present* (**pree-ZENT**) this *present* (**PREZ-uhnt**) to that *delegate* (**DELL-uh-guht**) so she will *ally* (**uh-LIE**) herself with us, but I'm going to *delegate* (**DELL-uh-GATE**) that task to my ally (**AL-eye**) so I can *desert* (**dee-ZERT**) this hot *desert*
  (**DEZ-uhrt**).

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, the pronunciation is important as it tells the listener which form of the word is being used.  This type of variation won't always be followed by all English speakers, but it will be followed by many and is therefore worth knowing:  it will definitely lead to clearer communication.

In terms of how important it is, I would say that it's not as important as clear written language:  you could consider it as "advanced knowledge" I think.  That's just my opinion.

In a lot of cases the pronunciation may vary due to regional differences (eg AmEng vs BrEng, or regional accents), or simple preference.  It's not required to learn all of these variations, and in fact may be impossible.